# ImportError: cannot import name 'NP_SUPPORTED_MODULES' from 'torch._dynamo.utils'

Tags: python, pytorch, cx-freeze, easyocr

```
try:
    import os
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    import xlsxwriter
    import sys,traceback
    import time,threading
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
    import requests
    import easyocr
    import certifi
    from datetime import datetime
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId
except:
    sys.stderr = open('../error.log', 'a+',encoding='utf-8')
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.stderr.close()

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en']) # this needs to run only once to load the model into memory
```

Traceback

```
(most recent call last):
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\osos_adanaorganize_scraper.py", line 9, in <module>
    import easyocr
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .easyocr import Reader
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\easyocr.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .recognition import get_recognizer, get_text
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\recognition.py", line 6, in <module>
    import torchvision.transforms as transforms
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from torchvision import _meta_registrations, datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\osos-scraper-_win_application\lib\torchvision\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .convnext import *
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\osos-scraper-_win_application\lib\torchvision\models\convnext.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ..ops.misc import Conv2dNormActivation, Permute
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .poolers import MultiScaleRoIAlign
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\poolers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .roi_align import roi_align
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\ops\roi_align.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch._dynamo
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\torch\_dynamo\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import allowed_functions, convert_frame, eval_frame, resume_execution
  File "D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\env\lib\site-packages\torch\_dynamo\allowed_functions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .utils import hashable, is_safe_constant, NP_SUPPORTED_MODULES
ImportError: cannot import name 'NP_SUPPORTED_MODULES' from 'torch._dynamo.utils' (D:\Developing\W.S-PROJECT\osos.adanaorganize.org.tr\osos-scraper-_win_application\lib\torch\_dynamo\utils.pyc)
```

when I am running the script in vs code is working.
but when I am creating an exe using cx_freeze, it is successfully created.
After I am running exe then gives me this error.